# optimizing functions php file

Tags: php, wordpress, function

for some extra needs i had to add some extra codes in fucnctions.php i notice slowing in my site i dont know if it has connection functions.php with jquery.js ,is there a anyway to optimize it ? its ok if i remove the entering space between the lines in fucntions.php id like to make as light as i can

```
/**
 * Adding Custom GTIN Meta Field
 * Save meta data to DB
 */
// add GTIN input field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data','woocom_simple_product_gtin_field', 10, 1 );
function woocom_simple_product_gtin_field(){
   global $woocommerce, $post;
   $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
   echo '<div id="gtin_attr" class="options_group">';
   //add GTIN field for simple product
   woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array(  
            'id'            => '_gtin',
            'label'         => __( 'GTIN', 'textdomain' ), 
            'placeholder'   => '01234567891231',
            'desc_tip'      => 'true',
            'description'   => __( 'Enter the Global Trade Item Number (UPC,EAN,ISBN)', 'textdomain' )
        )
    );
   echo '</div>';
}
// save simple product GTIN
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta','woocom_simple_product_gtin_save');
function woocom_simple_product_gtin_save($post_id){
   $gtin_post = $_POST['_gtin'];
   // save the gtin
   if(isset($gtin_post)){
      update_post_meta($post_id,'_gtin', esc_attr($gtin_post));
   }
   // remove if GTIN meta is empty
   $gtin_data = get_post_meta($post_id,'_gtin', true);
   if (empty($gtin_data)){
      delete_post_meta($post_id,'_gtin', '');
   }
}

add_filter( 'rank_math/snippet/rich_snippet_product_entity', function( $entity ) {
    global $post;
    $entity['gtin8'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'_gtin', true );
    return $entity;
});

/*
Tracking Info to WooCommerce order
Version: 0.4
$Id: tracking-info-to-wc-order.php 5168 2020-07-15 14:48:44Z damien $
*/


// Add the metabox to allow for manual entering (or editing) of tracking information.
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'dcwd_order_metabox' );
function dcwd_order_metabox() {
    $cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'            => 'order_tracking_info',
        'title'         => 'Tracking Information',
        'object_types'  => array( 'shop_order', ), // Post type
        'context'       => 'side',
        'priority'      => 'high',
        'show_names'    => true, // Show field names on the left
    ) );
    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name'  => 'Tracking number',
        'id'    => 'tracking_number',
        'type'  => 'text',
    ) );
    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name'       => 'Tracking URL',
        'id'         => 'tracking_url',
        'type'       => 'text_url',
        'protocols'  => array( 'http', 'https' ),
    ) );
}


// Examine the tracking url and return a provider name.
function dcwd_get_tracking_provider_from_url( $url ) {
    if ( strpos( $url, 'usps.com' ) !== false ) {
        return 'USPS';
    }
    if ( strpos( $url, 'fedex.com' ) !== false ) {
        return 'FexEd';
    }
    if ( strpos( $url, 'ups.com' ) !== false ) {
        return 'UPS';
    }
    // Add more as necessary.
    
    // Unknown provider.
    return null;
}


// If available, include the tracking information in the Completed Order email.
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'dcwd_add_tracking_info_to_order_completed_email', 5, 4 ); 
function dcwd_add_tracking_info_to_order_completed_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
/*  // Only customers need to know about the tracking information.
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
        return;
    }
*/
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ) {
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $tracking_number = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'tracking_number', true );
        $tracking_url = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'tracking_url', true );
        
        // Quit if either tracking field is empty.
        if ( empty( $tracking_number ) || empty( $tracking_url ) ) {
            // Debugging code.
            //error_log( sprintf( 'Order %d does not have both tracking number (%s) and url (%s)', $order_id, $tracking_number, $tracking_url ) );
            //echo '<p>Ne pare rău, informațiile de urmărire nu sunt disponibile în acest moment.</p>';
            return;
        }
        
        $tracking_provider = dcwd_get_tracking_provider_from_url( $tracking_url );

        if ( $plain_text ) {
            if ( ! empty( $tracking_provider ) ) {
                printf( "\nComanda dumneavoastra a fost expediata. %s. Numărul de urmărire este %s și îl poți urmări la %s.\n", $tracking_provider, esc_html( $tracking_number ), esc_url( $tracking_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) ) );
            }
            else {
                printf( "\nComanda dumneavoastra a fost expediata. Numărul de urmărire este %s și îl poți urmări la %s.\n", esc_html( $tracking_number ), esc_url( $tracking_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) ) );
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( ! empty( $tracking_provider ) ) {
                printf( '<p>Your order has been shipped with <strong>%s</strong>. The tracking number is <strong><a href="%s">%s</a></strong>.</p>', $tracking_provider, esc_url( $tracking_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) ), esc_html( $tracking_number ) );
            }
            else {
                printf( '<p>Comanda dumneavoastra a fost expediata. Numărul de urmărire este <strong><a href="%s">%s</a></strong>.</p>', esc_url( $tracking_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) ), esc_html( $tracking_number ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
// Display tracking information in My Account area.
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'dcwd_add_tracking_info_to_view_order_page', 5 );
function dcwd_add_tracking_info_to_view_order_page( $order_id ) {
    $tracking_number = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'tracking_number', true );
    $tracking_url = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'tracking_url', true );
        
    // Quit if either tracking field is empty.
    if ( empty( $tracking_number ) || empty( $tracking_url ) ) {
        // Debugging code.
        error_log( sprintf( 'Order %d does not have both tracking number (%s) and url (%s)', $order_id, $tracking_number, $tracking_url ) );
        echo '<p>Ne pare rău, informațiile de urmărire nu sunt disponibile în acest moment.</p>';
        return;
    }
        
    $tracking_provider = dcwd_get_tracking_provider_from_url( $tracking_url );
    if ( ! empty( $tracking_provider ) ) {
        printf( '<p>Comanda dvs. a fost expediată cu <strong>%s</strong>. Numărul de urmărire este <strong><a href="%s">%s</a></strong>.</p>', $tracking_provider, esc_url( $tracking_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) ), esc_html( $tracking_number ) );
    }
    else {
        printf( '<p>Comanda dumneavoastra a fost expediata. Numărul de urmărire este <strong><a href="%s">%s</a></strong>.</p>', esc_url( $tracking_url, array( 'http', 'https' ) ), esc_html( $tracking_number ) );
    }
}

function add_file_types_to_uploads($file_types){
$new_filetypes = array();
$new_filetypes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
$file_types = array_merge($file_types, $new_filetypes );
return $file_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_file_types_to_uploads');

function flatsome_result_count_and_catalog_ordering_remover() {
    remove_action( 'flatsome_category_title_alt', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20);
}
add_action('template_redirect','flatsome_result_count_and_catalog_ordering_remover');

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false' );

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );

function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );

    return true;
}
/**
 * @snippet       Remove Additional Information Tab @ WooCommerce Single Product Page
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 3.8
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'bbloomer_remove_product_tabs', 9999 );
  
function bbloomer_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); 
    return $tabs;
}

/**
 * Hide shipping rates when free shipping is available.
 * Updated to support WooCommerce 2.6 Shipping Zones.
 *
 * @param array $rates Array of rates found for the package.
 * @return array
 */
function my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 100 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customise_postcode_fields' );
function customise_postcode_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;

    return $address_fields;
}

if ( function_exists( 'yith_affiliates_install' ) ) {

    if ( ! function_exists( 'yith_wcaf_show_dashboard_links_call_back' ) ) {

        function yith_wcaf_show_dashboard_links_call_back() {

            return 'yes';
        }
    }

    add_filter( 'yith_wcaf_show_dashboard_links', 'yith_wcaf_show_dashboard_links_call_back' );

}
```

Comment: You want to remove the whitespace in your code, is that correct? If so, you can do that but it will have absolutely zero performance implications. This code itself _might_ be slowing your site down, but there's no way to be certain without knowing your actual site.

Comment: And functions.php has connection with  jquery.js ? because normally i have only 17 plugin in my website Script Evaluation
3,864 ms

Comment: To be honest, there are over 200 lines of code in there, so it is pretty hard to tell you what is doing what, you just need to debug. Open your developer tools and look into the network area to find large scripts. Profile your application to find which script is running the longest. Remove all of the code that you added to functions.php and re-add them one at a time to see which is causing performance issues. Look into a caching solution like WP Rocket. You're on PHP 7, right? Make sure opcode cache is installed. Is Redis an option?